# How to create array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I create an array of objects from calculating the size which is pre-defined? In this HTML the p tag is going to always contain the size of the list.

How can I create object like this `let cups = [{name:'James',id='1'},{name:'Johnson',id:'2'}]`

Suppose if the size in p tag is 3 and there will be three tr tag and it holds the same content name and id

```js
size_of_option = document.getElementById("size").value;
console.log(size_of_option);
let cups = [];
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="size">2</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
   <select name="plan" id="plan"> 
    <option value="free">Cook</option> 
    <option value="starter" selected>James</option> 
    <option value="professional">Professional</option> 
    <option value="corporate">Corporate</option> 
   </select>
   </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Edit: If I have select tag inside of td how to read  that value?

Comment: First of all, try something. Then if you get stuck, we can help.

Comment: You dont need the `size` at all. There are 2 rows, you make an array of 2 items. If there are 3 rows you make an array of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use querySelectorAll and then take the children (td) to get the values

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr')).map(({
  children
}) => ({
  name: children[0].textContent,
  id: children[1].textContent
}))

console.log(list)
```

```html
<div>
<p id="size">2</p>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<div>
```

Comment: Suppose i have select tag with selected option in td then its does not work for that and 
if i have header then  itcreate object for header too

Comment: @Akhi21 you should re edit your question and include the select html in the tr td and then will be getting a modified answer

Comment: @Akhi21 According to the OP this answer will fulfil it. If you have other situations like what you said you need to clarify them in the question or ask them in the separate ones which are more appropriate. Expanding the question in comments after accepting an answer is against this community [COC](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), so please don't do this.

Comment: ok @SMAKSS sure i will not do this again.

Comment: @Eugen Sunic could you please tell the answer for select case

Comment: you should post a question for the select case, other than that you should check if select DOM element exists before adding the data to the object, if yes pull out the data according to the tr td select structure, should not be too hard

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the tr list and get data from td childs from each tr item.

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => {
   const data = [];
   row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(col => { data.push(col.innerText)})
   console.log(data)
   cups.push({name: data[0], id: data[1]})
})
```